# How to use php-cs-fixer with vim for laravel?

Tags: laravel, vim, laravel-5, phpcs, php-cs-fixer

I have installed `php-cs-fixer` & using with `vim` plugin `https://github.com/stephpy/vim-php-cs-fixer`. I am using custom config file from `https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/.php_cs`. But I am having this issue where extra space after `@param` from `comment` block gets deleted.

How can I fix this? Thanks for in advance.

Laravel uses PSR2 coding standard.

From laravel.com about documentation -
Note that the `@param` attribute is followed by two spaces, the argument type, two more spaces, and finally the variable name:

```php
/**
 * Register a binding with the container.
 *
 * @param  string|array  $abstract
 * @param  \Closure|string|null  $concrete
 * @param  bool  $shared
 * @return void
 */
public function bind($abstract, $concrete = null, $shared = false)
{
    //
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for "phpdoc_align" fixer. See [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer):

[image]

Laravel uses many more from Symfony standard (marked by "@Symfony").

**But the best way to find all fixers for Laravel, would be in [PHP-CS-Fixer configuration](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/.php_cs#L7-L71) in Laravel repostiory.**

Comment: I was using the same but did not solve the issue. The custom config for phpcs is from laravel repo.

Comment: You'll probably have to use a CLI command. I do the same, even when I use PHPStorm.